# conditionally rendering b-alert upon request success

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am making a request to an API which can return an OK status or an Error status, I want to render the appropriate alert, so if status is OK i can show `success`- alert and if not successful i'll show `danger`-(basically the bootstrap tag for unsuccessful)

I am using bootstrap-vue's `b-alert` component.

On initial load on my page, i dont have any requests thus my `requestStatus` is `null` cause it doesn't exist.
Upon sending a request to the API it should change the request to either true or false.

This is my code right now :

```
     <b-alert  v-model="requestSuccess" variant="successStatus" dismissible>
            Request was successful! 
          </b-alert> 
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {

      data() {
       return{

       requestStatus: null

      },

      methods: {
      onSubmit() {
                     .get(`https://vat.erply.com/numbers?vatNumber=${this.form.country}${this.form.VATNumber}`) // sends request
        // How we handle the response
        .then((response) => {

          // Request was successful -> 200
          this.requestStatus = true 

        }) 
        .catch(response => {


          this.requestStatus = false 

        })

       }
     }
   } 
}
```

I am struggling with showing the unsuccessful alert on my page,
 how should i go about doing this?

The main things I'd need to change would be the `variant` and the content in the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code with simulated fetch promise, status handlers and computed alert variant. Hope this helps!

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      showAlert: false,
      isSuccess: false,
      message: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    alertVariant() {
      return this.isSuccess ? 'success' : 'danger'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    simulateFetch(p) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (p) resolve('fetch successful')
          else reject('fetch failed')
        }, 1000)
      })
    },
    getResult(p) {
      this.isLoading = true
      // reset statuses
      this.showAlert = false
      this.isSuccess = false
      this.message = ''

      // run simulated fetch with boolean parameter
      this.simulateFetch(p)
        .then(result => {
          // fetch successful
          this.isSuccess = true
          this.message = result
        }).catch(error => {
          // fetch failed
          this.isSuccess = false
          this.message = error
        }).finally(() => {
          // finally
          this.isLoading = false
          this.showAlert = true
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-button variant="success" @click="getResult(true)" :disabled="isLoading">simulate success</b-button>
    <b-button variant="danger" @click="getResult(false)" :disabled="isLoading">simulate fail</b-button>
    <hr>
    <b-alert v-model="showAlert" :variant="alertVariant" dismissible>
      <strong>result: </strong>{{message}}
    </b-alert>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Boussadjra's answer was a bit loose so I'm gonna share my full example on how I went by doing this.

I need to change these values `alertShow` `successStatus` `requestMessage`,

thus I define them here :

```
 data() {
  return {
    alertShow: false,
    successStatus: null,
    requestMessage: '',
```

and upon sending a request and getting back a positive request I change the data accordingly:

```
 .then((response) => {     
       // Request Alert Parameters if SUCCESS
              this.successStatus = 'success' 
              this.requestMessage = 'Request was succesfull!'
              this.alertShow = true;
```

the `.catch` is basically the same but with different values.